# st_centroid() does not lie within polygon on Lambert-93 shapefile

Tags: r, r-sf

I have this problem. i have a shapefile from [the IGN institute](https://wxs-telechargement.ign.fr/1yhlj2ehpqf3q6dt6a2y7b64/telechargement/inspire/CONTOURS-IRIS-2018-06-08$CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1__SHP__FRA_2018-06-08/file/CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1__SHP__FRA_2018-06-08.7z). I want to aggregate the shapefile according to a feature, then i want to plot the centroids of the resulting polygons.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
# load a shapefile and plot
sh = st_read("~/Downloads/CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1__SHP__FRA_2018-06-08/CONTOURS-IRIS/1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2018-06-00105/CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1_SHP_LAMB93_FXX-2017/CONTOURS-IRIS.shp",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# paris
p = sh %>%
  mutate(INSEE_N = as.integer(INSEE_COM)-75100) %>%
  filter((INSEE_N < 21) & (INSEE_N > 0))

# aggregate and plot centroid
p_arr = p %>%
  group_by(INSEE_COM) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(n)

plot(p_arr)
plot(st_geometry(st_centroid(p_arr)), pch = 3, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm surprised that those centroids are not contained in their respective polygons. as you can see i haven't touched the CRS specification, i just read the shapefile. what did i do wrong here?

**edit**

by the way, in WGS84 i cannto see the centroids at all:

```
p_wgs = st_transform(p,4326)
p_arr_wgs = p_wgs %>%
  group_by(INSEE_COM) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(n)

plot(p_arr_wgs,axes=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(st_centroid(p_arr_wgs)), pch = 3, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In st_centroid.sf(p_arr_wgs) :
  st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
2: In st_centroid.sfc(st_geometry(x), of_largest_polygon = of_largest_polygon) :
  st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

I saw the warning. but why not? the data looks not too far off? I expected to see at least *something*

```
> st_geometry(st_centroid(p_arr_wgs))
Geometry set for 20 features 
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 2.261954 ymin: 48.82841 xmax: 2.421378 ymax: 48.89257
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
POINT (2.336403 48.86258)
POINT (2.342896 48.86828)
POINT (2.360002 48.86287)
POINT (2.357606 48.85435)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong with ypour code, but below is working fine for me.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)
paris <- st_read("./SO-answers/CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1__SHP__FRA_2018-06-08/CONTOURS-IRIS/1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2018-06-00105/CONTOURS-IRIS_2-1_SHP_LAMB93_FXX-2017/CONTOURS-IRIS.shp",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p_arr <- paris %>%
  mutate(INSEE_N = as.integer(INSEE_COM)-75100) %>%
  filter((INSEE_N < 21) & (INSEE_N > 0)) %>%
  group_by(INSEE_COM) %>%
  summarise()

mapview( list( p_arr, st_centroid( p_arr ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that works for me as well! what's going on with the `plot` method here? I thought I was reasonably close to https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html here.

Answer (score 0):

oops, wait a second. this works!

```
plot(st_geometry(p_arr))
plot(st_geometry(st_centroid(p_arr)), pch = 3, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

[image]

so I can only do this on pure `geometry` objects, ie no overlaid features?